# Inversion when using "not only ~ but also."

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

Is the following sentence correct?

> Not only can the coverage be easily increased, but the topology can also be more robust.

Comment: Your sentence is flawless.

Comment: Inversion is not optional in this construction.

Comment: Yes, it's OK. "Not only" when fronted triggers subject-auxiliary inversion

Comment: I don't understand why you're looking for inversion there, and please be aware that sentence is not flawless.

Comment: Inversion is only in the negative-fronted clause; the second clause isn't negative and doesn't front, so it doesn't invert.